# How to add main-menu option in CentOS 8

Tags: rhel, gnome-3, centos8

For CentOS 7, a custom menu items can be added via the Main-Menu application. Now I have upgraded to CentOS 8 this option is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by manually adding applications in ***/usr/share/applications/*** directory. To add eclipse as a custom application add a new file ***/usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop*** with the following contents in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Exec=<path_to_eclipse>
Type=Application
Icon=<path_to_icon>
Categories=Application;
```

Comment: I had to use Categories=IDE;Development  to get it under Programming Menu in CentOS8